AB-test percentiles difference
I have two groups in AB-test, where I am measuring start of program running.
Since I have both A and B large observation samples, I put data randomly into N buckets. Inside each bucket I calculate percentiles. Now I have new samples with N observations and I can compare them using t-test.
After comparing I got unexpected results: 50 and 95 percentiles observation samples give p-value lower than 0.05, so these groups have difference. But by 75 percentile these samples have no difference with p-value = 0.2. How could it happen?

It's unclear what you are asking. Please reword your question. Percentiles of what? how do percentiles have p-values?

@ZoeAllen edited my question to be more clear

A statistical test failing to reject a hypothesis doesn't mean the hypothesis is true. Just like a statistical test rejecting a hypothesis doesn't mean the hypothesis is false. All of this is random, so our test will inevitably give us the wrong answer some of the time. I'm pretty sure that's the answer to your question, but I'm still not sure what the test statistic you are computing is.
